# SSRS Cascading Params without a dataset

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I've done many a cascading param in SSRS but ALL have used datasets, passing in a param value into a query, this time I want to know if a date selection can be done using only expressions.

Periodtype parameter has a value list of 'Day' Or 'Quarter' (those are the labels, the values are "D" and "Q").

I've set the default values of the start and end dates via SSRS expression if periodtype value is "D" then set start and end date to be beginning and end of previous day and if "Q" then similar with previous quarter.

This works when you start up the report, changing the default period type (D or Q).

It won't allow the date to be calculated dynamically when changing the periodtype, can it be done without queries, using just params and expressions, thank-you?

Comment: One the report is run, I don't think the ssrs will refresh the cascading parameter.. out of curiosity.. if it works with dataset.. why not just use a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, I think the issue is not so much to do with datasets, but a long standing issue with SSRS not refreshing parameters, or at least the defaults, even if you specify to always refresh it.

Typically you can force the update by changes the available values.

As an example ...

I set up 2 parameters, the first called `PeriodType` is a simple text parameter with two available values "Q" and "D", it also has a default value of "D"

The second parameter called `StartDate` is a `Date/Time` type.

The following three properties were all set to the exact same expression

Available Values: Specify Values - Label and Value properties

Default Values: Specify Values - Value property

[image]

[image]

Here is the expression which simply shows todays date if "D" is chosen or the 1st Jan if Q is chosen purely for illustration.

```
=IIF(Parameters!PeriodType.Value = "D", today(), CDATE("2022-01-01"))
```

I also set the advanced properties "Always Refresh" option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to experiment and this brings back memories of doing this before now. 

Tempted for ease of use to leave it open so user on the rare cases an adhoc is needed (as on subscription) they have to enter the values themselves.

So the takeaways is available values forces a refresh, default values wont, thanks for your guidance :)